# How do you get a Youtube Channel's links (website) from the youtube/v3/channels API?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Looking at the doc:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

I don't see any part to request to get the links or websites of a channel. If you go to any channel "About" page on their normal site outside the API it lists the channel's external websites in a section called "links".

Is there a way to request that google add this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I would recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/966b7dbde5b4da83f3c3236407beca4099f85c87/channels.php#L259-L304) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=about&id=CHANNEL_ID you will retrieve the links of the `About` section of the given YouTube channel in `item["links"]`.

[Example of YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA/about) (`UC9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA`) having such website URLs in its `About` tab. My API would return for it:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UC9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA",
            "countryChannelId": "UC9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA",
            "about": {
                "stats": {
                    "joinedDate": 1239321600,
                    "viewCount": 201152616,
                    "subscriberCount": 2320000
                },
                "description": "Videos all about computers and computer stuff. Sister channel of Numberphile.",
                "title": "Computerphile",
                "details": {
                    "location": null
                },
                "links": [
                    {
                        "url": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/computerphile",
                        "title": "Facebook"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/computer_phile",
                        "title": "Twitter"
                    }
                ],
                "handle": "@Computerphile"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: wow, very cool, so I can just curl https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHEoWlkGf-nSVdNk9b6SR0g/about and the json I want is right there in the response. huh. no quota, so easy. Are they ok with scraping like this?

Comment: TLDR: Is fixing the YouTube APIs, that most of the time doesn't work as documented, a violation of the rules ?
Honestly I quickly read the YouTube rules and I suspect that the solution I am proposing violates them. However, insofar as I give the world a way forward and provide tools that Google is unable to provide to scientists (within a reasonable time frame if they do so), I find that given the limited use of my tools it remains reasonable. In any case if it really bothers YouTube they can very easily prevent this reasonable use by using captchas, banning IPs and ask me to remove my repo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python3.9 script to do it without Youtube data API, only by scraping the page with [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/).
Feel free to improve it, i'm still a rookie with Python (and using element_handles [is discouraged in the Playwright documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle)).

It also uses this [URLSearchParams Python Module](https://pypi.org/project/URLSearchParams/) to clean the urls of each related content links (which are that long : https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=channel_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa3pPZENEajNSQTBiSU41eEhtYzhBREpST2RvUXxBQ3Jtc0tsSEhFQ3ZhSzNnQmdDUWNYd0NZZHZXRldmVUpVcnNmZEw5dXRBR1Y5dDl4ZG5RZ0p6YkQtTmh1WlI3TTRpbkRTb3NoZ2x3SmhYM0tMdzdwUmV1akRtc0IxaUdrZ3J4akF6cWQ4YldWdlZ4VDZpNy1VSQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Ftsuki.market%2Fcollections%2Fbasics-pre-order )

The parameter `_str_youtube_url` is the url of the channel about section (e.g https://www.youtube.com/@PewDiePie/about)

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from URLSearchParams import URLSearchParams

def get_youtube_channel_related_content(_str_youtube_url):
    lst_related_content_links = []
    try:
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch()
            context = browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True,
                                          user_agent='your_user_agent'
                                          )
            page = context.new_page()
            page.goto(_str_youtube_url)

            # clicking Yes on GDPR message (in french)
            page.get_by_role("button", name="Tout accepter").click()
            page.wait_for_selector('#links-container')

            # Selecting the links-container div
            links_container = page.locator('#links-container  a')
            if links_container.count() > 0:
                for element in links_container.element_handles():                    
                    if element.get_attribute('href') != None:                
                        lst_related_content_links.append(URLSearchParams(element.get_attribute('href')).get('q'))
            browser.close()
            return lst_related_content_links

    except Exception as ex:
        ...
```