# YouTube API is using the old quota - the quota before I got approved for more

Tags: youtube-data-api

I recently got approved for a large increase in quota for the youtube-v3-api for the data API.

[picture of quotas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvWqt.png)

As you can see in the photo, it looks like I've got a ton more quota available but it still maxes me out at 10k.

Do I have to do something to fix this, or maybe it's on YouTube's end?

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003145/why-am-i-getting-quota-exceeded-with-enough-quota-remaining

Comment: Seems like the YouTube team had to fix it in their case. Must not have been a permanent fix i guess.

Comment: I'd be happy to hop on a call with anyone who might need me to help them fix this.

Comment: https://media.makeameme.org/created/someone-please-help-cwpeg7.jpg

Comment: AFAIK YouTube team isn't *easily* reachable, may I ask you for what usage (like listing videos in playlists...) you use your quota as their may be quota-less workarounds ? You may be interested with the large quota available on [my website](https://yt.lemnoslife.com), see *Make YouTube Data API v3 request WITHOUT ANY KEY:*

Comment: I use the api for video searching currently. That service you provide is pretty cool ngl but does it violate Youtube's TOS?

Comment: kinda sus - wonder if he'd take my api key lol

Comment: May you share an example of URL that you request to the YouTube API ? See [my statement related to YouTube ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72650280/7123660).

Comment: I tried your api and it said your api key has expired.

Comment: Also i made an issue in google's issue tracker and received no assistance for 5 days. Wish there was someone i could call about this :(

Comment: For instance https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/videos?part=snippet&id=Q6gtj1ynstU works fine on my side. May you give a way to reproduce the bug you just mentioned.

Comment: I'll try it again. I might be doing something wrong on my end. 

But on the topic of this quota bug. I believe I found some useful information related to the problem!!! I think the new quota is working for my application when I run it locally. But when I run the api calls from my heroku app, the old limit is still in place.

Comment: Omg. It has to do with the api key! For some reason the api key i was using on heroku, was attatched to the old limit - I guess it was a key to a different project or something. But i updated it to the one i was using locally and it works now. Omg i feel dumb :)