# Python scraping json data based on the response tab

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube

I am scraping `about tab in youtube` to be able gather description of channels and store the data in my csv, it works but only if I setup manually in the code the actual number of tabs the channel about has.

It means some channels have 5 some 6 or 7 depends if they have also short videos if they have playlist etc...

**My working code:**

```
stats = json_data["contents"]["twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer"]["tabs"][5]["tabRenderer"]["content"]["sectionListRenderer"]["contents"][0]["itemSectionRenderer"]["contents"][0]["channelAboutFullMetadataRenderer"]
```

So basically I tried to do IF `if json_data['status_code'] == 0:` then post the code with 5 tabs but I dont know what to do next how to check if there is 5 or more TABS.

Comment: It seems that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72650280) on a very similar StackOverflow question solves your problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison you did not understand what I'm trying to do, I can scrape ABOUT description with that code bellow BUT the user must have this tabs: Home, Videos, Playlist, Community, About .. OR in total count 5, they can have shorts or live tab so it will be always + Tab and Im not able to compare if response json contains all this tabs ...

Comment: I think that I initially have perfectly understand your need, I was expecting you to deep the *open-source* link of how I proceeded in order for you to figure out [this precise line](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/966b7dbde5b4da83f3c3236407beca4099f85c87/channels.php#L269) that is what you are looking for. I use the fact that the `ABOUT` tab is always the last one, [as I investigated](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/48#issuecomment-1270271158).

Comment: @Jane1990 why not loop the items at `json_data["contents"]["twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer"]["tabs"]` and see which one is the "About" tab?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison oh thx for link I knew someone already have this issue I will check it out

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes if I only knew how